# IIS 7 ARR v3.0 URL Rewrite Different Domain

Tags: iis-7, arr

I need to take requests to **firstdomain.com/example/foo/bar** and serve up content from **seconddomain.com/example/foo/bar** but I want the end user to still see **firstdomain.com/example/foo/bar** in their browser. That rules out a 301/302 redirect.  I thought URL-rewrite would do the trick, but that has to be same domain.  I think ARR is what I need.  So, I've installed ARR v3.0 and rebooted my server.  Now that ARR v3.0 is installed, how do I go about configuring it to perform the desired request routing?

I should note seconddomain.com is a 3rd party hosted server, whereas firstdomain.com is hosted on a server on our network.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.seconddomain.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>  
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://www.seconddomain.com/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://www.firstdomain.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```